# Contents of Android heap dumps

Tags: android, heap-dump, hprof, eclipse-memory-analyzer

Android heap dumps contains information about running methods and the local parameters of the methods?
Are the method parameters stored in the heap?

Answer (score 0):

That information is usually part of the **stack**, not the heap.

The heap contains all memory that is dynamically allocated (e.g. objects, arrays, &c).

To clarify: if you pass an Object as a parameter to a method, then its content (i.e. its members) will be in the heap, but the pointer to it is in the stack.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I've taken a heap dump (.hprof) from my android app using DDMS and I analyze it with Eclise Memory Analyzer. I cannot find the local variables and parameters of the methods. Do you know how can I get such information in a snapshot?